# I can't connect my Samsung Galaxy SL GT-I9003 via USB

Tags: 2.2-froyo, usb, charging

I can't connect my Samsung Galaxy SL GT-I9003 via USB. When I try to connect via usb mode the phone doesn't respond, it only charges. I tried restarting and restoring my device, but it still won't connect. I want to update my Android OS from Froyo to Ginger Bread.

Comment: Have you istalled Samsung drivers on your PC? Google drivers from SDK are not supported by Samsung phones.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to start.
2. Type `device manager`.

Do you see some icon with a [yellow triangle exclamation mark](http://www.driverboost.com/driver-tutorial-center/images/clip_image003.jpg) in it?
If so, you probably did not install any drivers. Install the 
Samsung USB driver or the Google USB driver.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should download the, SAMSUNG KIES software, it will update the drivers and maybe it will help. Personally, I had some problem with my HTC device which I solved using the HTC sync manager.